# Discrete type Markov chains Long run proportions?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

A certain missile has a guidance control system. Course correction
signals form a sequence ${X_n; n \geq 0}$ where $X_n$ is the state of the system after
the nth signal is sent and received. The state space for X is:

0: No correction required,

1: Minor correction required,

2: Major correction required,

3: Abort and self-destruct.

Suppose that {Xn, n \geq 0} can be modeled as a discrete-time Markov chain
with one-step transition matrix

[image]

If the system is initially in state 1, find the probability that the missile will
self-destruct.

Hi, looking at this question, it looks like we need to find the long run proportion for state 0. Since we see that state 0 and 3 are reccurent. This means that $\pi_1=0$ and $ \pi_2 = 0$ as they are transient states. I tried finding long run proportiion for state 0 and 4 by $\pi = \pi P$ but cannot get the answer.

Comment: "it looks like we need to find the long run proportion for state 0" Not at all. You are asked for the probability to ever visit state 3, starting from state 1.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the theory, but I note that over two steps the state evolves
$$(0,1,0,0) \rightarrow (5/6, 5/36, 0, 1/36) 
\rightarrow (5/6 + 5/6(5/36), (5/36)^2, 0, 1/36+1/36(5/36))
$$
The long run proportion for state 3 should be
$$
\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{36}\left(\frac{5}{36}\right)^t
=\frac{1}{31}
$$

Comment: @Malcolm Condition on the hitting time of step 3, and please consider making your comment an answer.

Comment: @GNUSupporter I have added an answer based on the comment above.  I'm sorry, i don't understand the first part of your comment "Condition on the hitting time of step 3".

Comment: @Malcolm Do you know [C-K equation](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-MCI.pdf)?  (Prop 1.4)

Comment: $$P(1 \to \dots \to 3) = P(1 \to 3 \text{ in 2 steps}) + P(1 \to 3 \text{ in 4 steps}) + \dots $$

Comment: @GNUSupporter Nice.  So i guess this is what I've done.  I will read the reference you gave.  Thanks.

Comment: There is a two lines solution, completely standard, which avoids inverting a matrix or summing a geometric series... but since the OP already accepted an answer, one would be afraid to be a nuisance by adding it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an absorbing Markov chain, so there is no unique limiting distribution $\pi$ such that $$\pi(j) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P(X_n=j) $$ for each state $j$. Re-order the states $(1,2,0,3)$ to obtain
$$
P = \pmatrix{0&1/6&5/6&0&\\5/6&0&0&1/6\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1} = \pmatrix{Q&R\\0&I_2},
$$
where $Q$ is the substochastic matrix corresponding to transitions between transient states and $R$ is the substochastic matrix corresponding to transitions from transient states to absorbing states. Let $N$ the matrix be defined by $$N_{ij} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathsf 1_{\{X_n=j\ \mid\  X_0=i\}},  $$
then $N=\sum_{n=0}^\infty Q^n$. Since $Q$ is a substochastic matrix, this series converges and is equal to $(I-Q)^{-1}$. We compute
$$
(I-Q)^{-1}=\pmatrix{1&-1/6\\-5/6&1}^{-1} =\pmatrix{36/31&6/31\\30/31&36/31},
$$
and so the expected number of transitions until absorption when starting in transient state $i$ is the $i^{\mathsf{th}}$ entry of
$$
N\cdot\mathbf 1 = \pmatrix{36/31&6/31\\30/31&36/31}\pmatrix{1\\1}=\pmatrix{42/31\\66/31}.
$$
The probability of being absorbed in state $j$ when starting in state $i$ is the $(i,j)$-entry of
$$
NR = \pmatrix{36/31&6/31\\30/31&36/31}\pmatrix{5/6&0\\0&1/6}=\pmatrix{30/31&1/31\\25/31&6/31}.
$$

Comment: "This is an absorbing Markov chain, so there is no limiting distribution" Actually, there are always some, and infinitely many in the present case.

Comment: @Did By "no limiting distribution" I mean there is no distribution $\pi$ such that $\pi(j) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P(X_n=j)$.

Comment: Indeed the chain has a limiting distribution, for every starting distribution, and it is concentrated on $\{0,3\}$.

Comment: It does not have a *unique* limiting distribution.

Comment: True in general, but for every given initial distribution, for example the one the OP is asking about (namely, a Dirac mass at state 1), there is a unique limiting distribution. Please modify your post.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I don't know the best way to approach this problem, but a possible approach  follows.

The system is initially ($n=0$) in state 1, $p = (0,1,0,0)$ where $p_i$ is the probability of state $i$, $i = 0,\ldots , 3$.

Using the given transition probabilities, for $n=1$,
$
p=(5/6, 0, 1/6, 0)
$
$$\text{For }
n = 2, \quad
p = (5/6, 5/36, 0,1/36 ).
$$

$$\text{For }
n = 4, \quad
p = \left(\frac{5}{6}+\frac{5}{6}\frac{5}{36}, \left(\frac{5}{36}\right)^2, 0,\frac{1}{36} + \frac{1}{36}\frac{5}{36} \right).
$$

$$\text{For }
n = 2t, \quad
p = \left(\frac{5}{6}+\frac{5}{6}\frac{5}{36}+\cdots+\frac{5}{6}\left(\frac{5}{36}\right)^{t-1}, \left(\frac{5}{36}\right)^t, 0,\frac{1}{36} + \frac{1}{36}\frac{5}{36}+\cdots +\frac{1}{36}\left(\frac{5}{36}\right)^{t-1} \right)
$$

In the limit, the long run probability of state 3 is
$$
\frac{1}{36}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{5}{36}\right)^t = \frac{1}{31}
$$